# SVN branching problems

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I have a /Trunk in my Project X. On rev 69 we had to revert changes in three earlier revisions (61,63,64).

What I did was a reverse merge on the revisions 61,63,64 and committed this to rev 69. Then we could deploy again and everyone was happy.

Now we have learned that developing new features in a separate branch is a neat idea, and then the Trunk is always ready to deploy to production (and doing hotfixes on current release).

So now I have made a "/Branches/X"(rev 70) from the HEAD revision in the /Trunk (which is rev 69), but I want to have with me the changes I undid in the /Trunk (61,63,64)

What is the correct way to this?

btw, have I made meself clear about? :)

Comment: It is better to use trunk for the current development version, use tags to mark releases and branches for release bug fixes and experimental features. http://ariejan.net/2006/11/24/svn-how-to-structure-your-repository has reasonable discussion of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, watch your spell-checker: `trunk` and `branches` are conventionally all lower-case. That said, you should remove your branch and recreate it from revision 68.

```
svn delete <project_url>/branches/X -m"branch X removed"

svn copy <project_url>/trunk@68 project_url/branches/X -m"New branch X"
```

Here I'm assuming that revision 68 contains all changes from revs. 61,63,64 and nothing you do not want.

I'm sure you already realized that you can't go far without [the Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can just merge them again, now to the branch:

```
svn merge -r60:64 url://trunk wc-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, suppose that you want to merge some change-sets from branch X to branch Y. do the following steps using TortoiseSVN:

1. Get Y in working folder Y-WF.
2. Go to Y-WF.
3. Right click and choose merge.
4. For the source url, enter the URL of the X branch.
5. Select your change-sets you want to merge.
6. Press OK.
7. Now, the changes have been applied to your working folder. (in the case of no conflicts)
8. Check-in all of your changes.